# SDL2 draw pixels routines vs drawing from texture on Android

Tags: android, c++, sdl-2

Which one is faster for performance? I am doing a Tetris game and i have implemented a lot of routines who involve functions `SDL_RenderDrawLine` and `SDL_RenderDrawPoint` from the SDL2_GFX library and others functions that i made myself who use this 2 functions to draw primitives or lines, but in general i see more people using sprites which are drawn from textures.

At the time I don't complain on speed but may be in a future with more animations and routines...

Comment: I don't think you'll ever have performance problems with a Tetris clone in either case.

Comment: You could profile that by yourself. Just draw your primitives in a loop and increase the amount until it starts to lag.

Comment: I'm starting to get delayed animations on **Android** :( (when a tetris line is made i make the floor to tremble) not on **PC** or in my case **OS X**. If all **SDL** animations on **Android** are that way slow shouldn't be announced as a multi-platform lib, i think i'm making a mistake here.